# Python reference to regex in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that needs to have the letter 't' removed if it is not immediately preceded by a number.

I am trying to do this using re.sub and I have this:

```
f=open('File.txt').read()
g=f
g=re.sub('([^0-9])t','',g)
```

This identifies the letters to be removed correctly but also removes the preceding character.  How can I refer to the parenthesized regex in the replacement String?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a lookbehind (or negative lookbehind) instead.

```
g=re.sub('(?<=[^0-9])t','',g)
```

or

```
g=re.sub('(?<![0-9])t','',g)
```

Comment: This also avoids the problem of overlapping matches, where the original regex would only see one match in `'tt'`.

Answer (score 3):

Three options:

```
g=re.sub('([^0-9])t','\\1',g)
```

or

```
g=re.sub('(?<=[^0-9])t','',g)
```

or

```
g=re.sub('(?<![0-9])t','',g)
```

The first option is what you are looking for, a backreference to the captured string. `\\1` will refer to the first captured group.

Lookarounds don't consume characters, so you don't need to replace them back. Here, I have used a positive lookbehind for the first one and a negative lookbehind for the second one. Those don't consume the characters within their brackets, so you are not taking the `[^0-9]` or `[0-9]` in the replacement. It might be better to use those since it prevents overlapping matches.

The positive lookbehind makes sure that `t` has a non-digit character before it. The negative lookbehind makes sure that `t` does not have a digit character before it.

Comment: I tried \1 but I believe it's a reserved character for something else in python. Other option works though, thanks.

Comment: @macklin Hmm, maybe try `g=re.sub('([^0-9])t', r'\1',g)` for the first one. I'm not that used to python yet ^^;